# scope variable in my controller not working src of ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm trying to load my ng-include dynamically by putting a $scope variable in the 'src' tag. Here's my code:

In controller:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.requests = {
        "0": { url: '/tpl-first-request.html' },
        "1": { url: '/tpl-second-request.html' }
    };

    $scope.getRequest = getRequest;

    function getRequest(request) {
        $scope.request = $scope.requests[request].url;
    }
});
```

In html:

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="getRequest(0)">Click first one</button>
    <button ng-click="getRequest(1)">Click second one</button>
    <p ng-if="request">Request = {{request}}</p>
    <div ng-include src="request"></div>
</body>
```

The ng-include is not working, but the printout of "Request = {{request}}" is working fine.. You can test it in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jq2p1jwrcqEbbfTPUkiR?p=preview)

Comment: @RohitKumar This does not work! Try it in my plunker..

Answer (score 1):

Remove the slash from `request` path.

```
  $scope.requests = {
    "0": { url: 'tpl-first-request.html' },
    "1": { url: 'tpl-second-request.html' }
  };
```

This do the job, at least in my [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/oD0hAe8ZViPytupP88UB?p=preview).

Comment: Not working with me.. How can your example work if your not including request.html?

Answer (score 0):

It's a plunker problem, you're using absolute URLs for your templates instead of relatives ones:

```
  $scope.requests = {
    "0": { url: 'tpl-first-request.html' },
    "1": { url: 'tpl-second-request.html' }
  };
```

working plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/iTZJ64YyyxqbQyC1bOKS?p=preview